# gem annotate, error:Unable to annotate app/models/blog_post.rb: undefined method `supports_foreign_keys?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ruby 2.0.0p247

Rails 3.2.22

mysql

I added gem 'annotate'
after bundle install. gem was installed

Next step: rails g annotate:install

next step: run rake db:migrate

Display error:

**Unable to annotate app/models/blog_post.rb: undefined method `supports_foreign_keys?' for    ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0x0000000346aae8**

Similarly for other models

What wrong? How solve this issue. Thank you.

**EDIT**

shema.rb

```
.........................
create_table "blog_posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id",                            :null => false
    t.string   "subject"
    t.text     "body",                               :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "comments_count",  :default => 0,     :null => false
    t.boolean  "delta",           :default => true,  :null => false
    t.string   "tags_line"
    t.string   "commentable_by",  :default => "all", :null => false
    t.string   "visible_by",      :default => "all", :null => false
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.boolean  "draft",           :default => false, :null => false
    t.datetime "published_at"
    t.datetime "last_comment_at"
  end

  add_index "blog_posts", ["delta"], :name => "index_blog_posts_on_delta"
  add_index "blog_posts", ["user_id"], :name => "index_blog_posts_on_user_id"
........................................................................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the versions of your annotate-gem and your mysql2-gem are not compatible. You are still using Rails 3.2. Maybe it is because your mysql2-gem is quite old.
When looking at the [release notes](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rdoc) of the annotate-gem, you can see that it had added foreign_key support in 2.6.9. So it can help to downgrade it to 2.6.8